# How to change navigation bar title when view loads

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

I need to read one value and use it to set title in navigation bar.
I am using `react-native-router-flux` and I also use redux.
I navigate to view where I set language and fire redux action.
All views receive new state and in `render()` method I can call:

```
console.log(this.props.language.language)
```

This is set through redux.
And I want to change navigation bar title like:

```
Actions.refresh({title: I18n.t('main', {locale: this.props.language.language})})
```

But this slows down application and don't work.
But don't know where to put it if not in `render` method.

Comment: what navigation bar are you using? a custom one?

Answer (score 1):

You can change navigation title by setting navigation params as follows:

```
this.props.navigation.setParams({
    title: 'YOUR_DESIRED_TITLE_HERE',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be modifying state in your `render` methods - this will result in an infinite loop of changing state causing re-renders.

Instead you should put this in a lifecycle method:

```
componentDidMount () {
  Actions.refresh(...)
}
```

Which will be fired when the component is first mounted.

Comment: But component is already mounted. It's first screen then I navigate to second and changed language. I son't know how to make update in first screen now. Is there some method like viewWillApper in ios, fired whenever screen is shown?

Comment: The closest thing would be [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) which is passed new props whenever they change.

Comment: This method also doesn't help. It is not called when I open view it is called when I update state via redux. At that time that screen is not visible so again I can't update title.

Answer (score 0):

You could try storing the current language in a closure that is globally accessible throughout the application.

This will allow you to set the language state in the `constructor` of your components, which ensures that it will be present throughout the life cycle of the component.

```
// Settings.js
var Settings = (function() {
  var language = "EN"; // The default language

  var getLanguage = function() {
    return language;
  };
  var setLanguage = function(lang) {
    language = lang;
  };

  return {
    getLanguage: getLanguage,
    setLanguage: setLanguage
  }
})();

export default Settings;
```

When you want to get the current language, and set state in your component:

```
import Settings from './Settings';
... 
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    language: Settings.getLanguage()
  }
}
```

When you want to set or change the current language:

```
import Settings from './Settings';
... 
Settings.setLanguage('FR');

// Do something like reload here?
```

Answer (score 0):

If I clearly understand your question you should use React Lifecycle method [componentWillReceiveProps()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    let { language } = nextProps.language;
    if (language && language != this.props.language.language) {
      Actions.refresh({title: I18n.t('main', {locale: language})})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're missing is the key of the component, where your keys are defined in Router > Scene tree.

```
Actions.refresh({key: 'somekey', title: I18n.t('main', {locale: this.props.language.language})})
```

However, it may just not about it, and from my experiences, I can help you with a sneaky hack. This is a workaround I discovered when Actions doesn't work even though component has already been mounted.

Just wrap your action with a timeout, and it works. This workaround originally inspired from the fact that firing two Action commands consecutively will omit the first one.

Place it in `componentDidMount(){}` or in `componentWillReceiveProps(){}` if you like Redux to trigger this function as well.

```
setTimeout(() => {
   Actions.refresh({key: 'somekey', title: I18n.t('main', {locale: this.props.language.language})}, 200); // give him some space!
});
```

Hope this is really the case.